# How to single value from <select> and assign to href link using php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to  select option  from a select box contain values is already fetched from the database

am using the code

**code part select box**

```
$qry="select username from login where type='reviewer'";
$result =mysql_query($qry);
echo "<td><select name='dropdown' id='dropdown'>";
while($r= mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    //echo "<option value=".$r[0].">".$r[0]."</option>";
    echo "<option value=$r[0]>$r[0]</option>";
}
echo "</select></td>";
```

Above code shows to fetch the from database its already working.  Using a `href` to pass mutiple values `<a href='assignforrevdb.php?paperid=$row[0]&dropdown=dropdown&status=Pending'>Assign</a>` method is post. But my problem I found is query passing only
two values which are `paperid` and `status`. No value in third field it is reviewer is there any solution?

**Echo query string**

```
echo query UPDATE upload-data SET REVIEWER='',STATUS='Pending', WHERE paperid='39'
```

Comment: [**`mysql_*`**](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) is deprecated and soon to be dropped. It is advised to move to either [**`mysqli_*`**](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php) or [**`pdo`**](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php)

Comment: The value ouput at `echo "<option value=$r[0]>$r[0]</option>";` should have quotes around the output, eg, `echo "<option value='$r[0]'>$r[0]</option>";`

Comment: @ʰᵈˑsir i am a beginner in php and mysql

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, this is what I think you need.
This will work with bootstrap libary:

```
echo'    <div class="dropdown text-right">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Select Reviewer
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">';
        $queried1 = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM login WHERE type='reviewer'")
         or die(mysql_error());
        while ($result1 = mysql_fetch_array($queried1)) {
            echo '<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="assignforrevdb.php?paperid=' . $row[0] . '&username=' . $result1['username'] . '&status=Pending">' . $result1['username'] . '</li>';
        }
            echo'
      </ul>
    </div>';
```

Add this to your header to make it work:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: " This will work with bootstrap libary" It will work without it too, it just won't style is properly, right?

Comment: you are right, but it will not be a dropdown without

Comment: Ah okay! In that case, link OP to the bootstrap library, considering your answer relies on it. Also, there are no PHP tags, unless there is an `echo '` on line 0.

Comment: @user3253002 Thanks for your comment. I try this the problem is it only shows a drop down box

Comment: @user3253002 its only shows dropdown box. there is no value fetch from database.

Comment: try this: `echo '<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="assignforrevdb.php?paperid=' . $row[0] . '&username=' . $result1['username'] . '&status=Pending">' . $result1['username'] . '</li>';`